# pass data from tabbar controller to view controller in swift and xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass data from a view controller to tabbar controller, and then from this tab bar controller to its view controller with using their class. I succeeded to transfer from view controller to tabbar controller using segue. However, I cannot transfer data from tabbar controller to its one of the view controller.

Any idea/documentation will be appreciated. Here is the screenshot about what I want to do from xcode
[screenshot-xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suCqU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller) for the tab bar controller, in particular the `viewControllers` property.

That property is an array of `UIViewController`s, in the order they appear in the tab bar, so you can pick the one you need (`viewControllers[0]` from your screen shot), cast it to your specific view controller subclass and then  pass it your data.

Answer (score 2):

At last, I am able to solve the issue, many thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029517?noredirect=1). Here is the detailed explanation for beginners like me:

This is the source controller class, which is a tabbar controller and it transfers the data:

```
class SourceTC: UITabBarController {

    var dataTransferFrom = "transfer this string"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let finalVC = self.viewControllers![0] as! DestinationVC //first view controller in the tabbar
        finalVC.dataTransferTo = dataTransferFrom

    }

}
```

and this is the destination controller class, which is a view controller under tabbar controller and it gets the transferred data:

```
class DestinationVC: UIViewController {

    var dataTransferTo = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(dataTransferTo)

    }
}
```